# GREP and RegEx - find pattern and look for it again

Tags: regex, grep

Here's what I want to do:

Search a document for a pattern containing RegEx, then check if this exact pattern is present twice inside of a line.

```
Content of file.xml:
(some code) "testen"  (more code)  >testete<
(some code) "bleiben" (more code)  >bleiben<
(some code) "stehen"  (more code)  >stand<
(some code) "hängen"  (more code)  >hängten<
...
```

Now I want to check for `.*en` and check if the (exact) same word occurs twice in the line. So the outcome should be:

```
bleiben
```

Because Testen != testete, stehen != stand, hängen != hängten

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can handle this search on the first `grep` line by using the pattern: `.*en.*en`:

```
grep .*en.*en your_file
```

This will output only the lines that have `en` appearing twice in them.

If you *need* to handle it in two back-to-back `grep`'s, you could still use this same command in a piped version:

```
grep .*en your_file | grep .*en.*en
```

Also, if you ever want to increase the number of instances in the same line, you can take advantage of `grep`'s `-P` option and use a Perl regex:

```
grep -P "(.*en){2}" your_file
```

With this, you can just change the `{2}` to however-many instances you want it to appear in a single line and it should work.

**EDIT** (to find lines with *exact same word* twice)

This is difficult without an extended pattern that can define the boundaries of a word - and your example output doesn't really help much. To go for a straight-to-the-point example, we can just assume a "word" is any alphabetical string `a-z` that's ending with `en`. You can customize this boundary as needed:

```
grep -P "([a-z]+en).*\1" your_file
```

This will print any line that has a word ending in `en` that is found elsewhere in the line (the `\1`).

One caveat to mention, which relates to the word-boundary issue noted above. In the context of "bleiben" and "bleiben", they are equal. However, in the context of "ben" and "bleiben", this pattern will *also* match because it will see then ending "ben" from "bleiben" as the matching pattern (thereby using "ben" = "ben"). If this is not acceptable, you will have to establish a more-strict word-boundary (i.e. - don't allow special characters?).

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, it will give me back the line "hängen - hängten" too...I need a way (if it's possible) to chekc if it's the exact same word, if it ends on "en" is just to narrow to a specific word-type

Comment: I've edited my answer to, hopefully, fit your requirements a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. I'm assuming by twice you mean two or more times. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file.xml
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
/.*en/ { 
    gsub(/["<>]/, " ")
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ /.*en/) {
            array[$i]++
        } 
    }
}
{
    for (j in array) {
        if (array[j]>=2) {
            print j
        }
    }
    delete array
}
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk '/.*en/ { gsub(/["<>]/, " "); for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /.*en/) array[$i]++ } { for (j in array) if (array[j]>=2) print j; delete array }' file.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -rn 's/.*\b(\w+en)\b.*\b\1\b.*/\1/gp' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep's `-o` option to *only return the matching portion* of the line.

Here's a link that suggests that awk might be a better tool for the job:

- http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.awk/match-0-or-twice-the-same-word/197049

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
sed -n  's/[^"]\+"\([^"]\+\)"[^>]\+>\1</\1/p' FileName.txt
```

**Output :**

```
bleiben
```

Comment: Hi vara and welcome. If you add an empty line and then 4 spaces in front of your code line, then it will be considered source code. This saves time regarding formatting and it will print nicer. I haven't edited your post as I would normally do as I'm afraid of messing up the regexp :)